# SPServices Cascade Dropdowns not working when MDS feature is Activated

Tags: lookup-column, spservices

I have configured SharePoint lists (County, State and City) with corresponding lookups and everything work if MDS feature is not activated.

Now issue comes when using with MDS feature activated. Browser console shows error **"Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference"**

When I checked SPServices js the error comes at line shown below

[image]

I have also configured it to work with MDS like

```
if ("undefined" != typeof g_MinimalDownload && g_MinimalDownload && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()).endsWith("/_layouts/15/start.aspx") && "undefined" != typeof asyncDeltaManager) {

RegisterModuleInit("/SiteAssets/Cascade_Dropdown.js", SetCityCascadeDropdowns);}
```

Is anyone faced this issue?

Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working by using **ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded** inside the function which is called in **RegisterModuleInit**
The complete script is like

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    SetCityCascadeDropdownsMDS();
}); 

function SetCityCascadeDropdownsMDS()
{
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SetCityCascadeDropdowns, "sp.js");

}
function SetCityCascadeDropdowns()
{

    if (document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf("/lists/city/newform.aspx") != -1 || document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf("/lists/city/editform.aspx") != -1)
    {
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
           relationshipList: "State", //The name of the list which contains the parent/child relationships
           relationshipListParentColumn: "Country", //The StaticName of the parent column in the relationshipList
           relationshipListChildColumn: "Title", //The StaticName of the child column in the relationshipList
           parentColumn: "Country", //The DisplayName of the parent column in the form
           childColumn: "State", //The DisplayName of the child column in the form
           debug: true
          });
    }

}
// // Is MDS enabled?
if ("undefined" != typeof g_MinimalDownload && g_MinimalDownload && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()).endsWith("/_layouts/15/start.aspx") && "undefined" != typeof asyncDeltaManager) {
    RegisterModuleInit("/Style Library/Cascade_Dropdown.js", SetCityCascadeDropdownsMDS); //MDS registration
}
```